# Exact Change with Java

Tags: java

I am struggling with a homework assignment for a Java class. My code is listed below.
I am having a problem with my dollars and quarters and outputting correctly, I am not sure what the mistake is, with the quarters or dollars? For example, I am getting the error from my lab -

> *" Output differs. See highlights below.
>
> Input: 141
>
> Your output
>
> 1 Dollar
> 1 Dime
> 1 Nickel
> 1 Penny
>
> Expected output
>
> 1 Dollar
> 1 Quarter
> 1 Dime
> 1 Nickel
> 1 Penny "*

> *Input: 45
>
> Your output
>
> 2 Dimes
>
> Expected output
>
> 1 Quarter
> 2 Dimes*

The prompt is as follows;

> *Write a program with total change amount in pennies as an integer input, and output the change using the fewest coins, one coin type per line. The coin types are Dollars, Quarters, Dimes, Nickels, and Pennies. Use singular and plural coin names as appropriate, like 1 Penny vs. 2 Pennies.*
>
> *Ex: If the input is:
> 0
>
> the output is:
>
> No change*
>
> *Ex: If the input is:
> 45
> the output is:
>
> 1 Quarter
>
> 2 Dimes*

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
    int cents = scnr.nextInt();

    int numDollars = (cents / 100) % 100;
    int numQuarters = (cents % 25) / 25;
    int numDimes    = (cents % 25) / 10;
    int numNickels  = ((cents % 25) % 10) / 5;
    int numPennies  = ((cents % 25) % 10) % 5;

// no change
      if (cents == 0) {
         System.out.println("No change");
      }
      
// dollars
      if (numDollars < 2 && numDollars >=1) {
      System.out.println(numDollars + " Dollar");
      }
      
      else if (numDollars >=2) {
      System.out.println(numDollars + " Dollars");
      }

// quarters
      if (numQuarters < 2 && numQuarters >=1) {
      System.out.println(numQuarters + " Quarter");
      }
      
      else if (numQuarters >=2) {
      System.out.println(numQuarters + " Quarters");
      }
      
// dimes      
      if (numDimes < 2 && numDimes >=1) {
      System.out.println(numDimes + " Dime");
      }
      
      else if (numDimes >=2) {
      System.out.println(numDimes + " Dimes");
      }
      
// nickels      
      if (numNickels < 2 && numNickels >=1) {
      System.out.println(numNickels + " Nickel");
      }
      
      else if (numNickels >=2) {
      System.out.println(numNickels + " Nickels");
      }

// pennies      
      if (numPennies < 2 && numPennies >=1) {
      System.out.println(numPennies + " Penny");
      }
      
      else if (numPennies >=2) {
      System.out.println(numPennies + " Pennies");
      }
      
      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mistake is trying overly complicated formulas to calculate the coin amounts.

Just do what you would do in the real world: grab full dollars until that's no longer possible. See how much is left. Grab quarters until that's no longer possible. See how much is left. And so on.

Comment: this^  Also, add System outs after you calculate everything and see what your calculations show. For instance, I think the formula determine the dollars is incorrect. Put a system out to see what your calculation produces and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

So in defining int's I would change the logic of your formula after the dollar, and first lines for singular use should be == not >= but I would suggest this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      int cents = scnr.nextInt();

      int numDollars = (cents / 100) % 100;
      int numQuarters = (cents % 100) / 25;
      int numDimes    = (cents % 25) / 10;
      int numNickels  = (((cents % 25) % 10) / 5);
      int numPennies  = (((cents % 25) % 10) % 5);

      // no change
      if (cents == 0) {
         System.out.println("No change");
      }
      
      // dollars
      if (numDollars < 2 && numDollars == 1) {
         System.out.println(numDollars + " Dollar");
      }
      
      else if (numDollars >= 2) {
          System.out.println(numDollars + " Dollars");
      }
      
      // quarters
      if (numQuarters < 2 && numQuarters == 1) {
          System.out.println(numQuarters + " Quarter");
      }
      
      else if (numQuarters >= 2) {
          System.out.println(numQuarters + " Quarters");
      }
      
      // dimes      
      if (numDimes < 2 && numDimes == 1) {
          System.out.println(numDimes + " Dime");
      }
      
      else if (numDimes >= 2) {
          System.out.println(numDimes + " Dimes");
      }
      
      // nickels      
      if (numNickels < 2 && numNickels == 1) {
          System.out.println(numNickels + " Nickel");
      }
      
      else if (numNickels >= 2) {
          System.out.println(numNickels + " Nickels");
      }
      
      // pennies      
      if (numPennies < 2 && numPennies == 1) {
          System.out.println(numPennies + " Penny");
      }
      
      else if (numPennies >= 2) {
          System.out.println(numPennies + " Pennies");
      }
      
      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in defining int's I would change the logic of your formula after the dollar, and first lines for singular use should be == not >= but I would suggest this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      int cents = scnr.nextInt();

      int numDollars = (cents / 100) % 100;
      int numQuarters = (cents / 25) % 25;
      int numDimes    = (cents / 10) % 10;
      int numNickels  = ((cents / 5) % 5);
      int numPennies  = ((cents / 1) % 1);

      // no change
      if (cents == 0) {
         System.out.println("No change");
      }
      
      // dollars
      if (numDollars < 2 && numDollars == 1) {
         System.out.println(numDollars + " Dollar");
      }
      
      else if (numDollars >= 2) {
          System.out.println(numDollars + " Dollars");
      }
      
      // quarters
      if (numQuarters < 2 && numQuarters == 1) {
          System.out.println(numQuarters + " Quarter");
      }
      
      else if (numQuarters >= 2) {
          System.out.println(numQuarters + " Quarters");
      }
      
      // dimes      
      if (numDimes < 2 && numDimes == 1) {
          System.out.println(numDimes + " Dime");
      }
      
      else if (numDimes >= 2) {
          System.out.println(numDimes + " Dimes");
      }
      
      // nickels      
      if (numNickels < 2 && numNickels == 1) {
          System.out.println(numNickels + " Nickel");
      }
      
      else if (numNickels >= 2) {
          System.out.println(numNickels + " Nickels");
      }
      
      // pennies      
      if (numPennies < 2 && numPennies == 1) {
          System.out.println(numPennies + " Penny");
      }
      
      else if (numPennies >= 2) {
          System.out.println(numPennies + " Pennies");
      }
      
      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking something like this. But for some reason i am getting only answers in dollars and pennies. It is skipping the other 3 if statements.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int pennies;
      int dollars;
      int quarters;
      int nickels;
      int dimes;
      int userInput;
  
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); 
      userInput = scnr.nextInt();
  
      if(userInput != 0){
     
  
         dollars = userInput/100;
         userInput = userInput - dollars*100;
     
         quarters = userInput/100;
         userInput = userInput - quarters*25;
     
         dimes = userInput/100;
         userInput = userInput - dimes*10;
     
         nickels = userInput/100;
         userInput = userInput - nickels*5;
     
         pennies = userInput;
     
     
         if ( dollars == 1){
            System.out.println ("1 Dollar");
         }
         else if ( dollars > 1){
            System.out.println (dollars+" Dollars");
         }
     
         if ( quarters == 1){
            System.out.println ("1 Quarter");
         }
         else if ( quarters > 1){
            System.out.println (quarters+" Quarters");
         }
     
         if ( dimes == 1){
            System.out.println ("1 Dime");
         }
         else if ( dimes > 1){
            System.out.println (dimes+" Dimes");
         }
     
         if ( nickels == 1){
            System.out.println ("1 Nickel");
         }
         else if ( nickels > 1){
            System.out.println (nickels+" Nickels");
         }
         if ( pennies == 1){
            System.out.println ("1 Penny");
         }
         else if ( pennies > 1){
            System.out.println (pennies+" Pennies");
         }
      }
      else {
       System.out.println("No change");  
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: dollars = userInput/100;
         userInput = userInput - dollars*100;
     
         quarters = userInput/25;
         userInput = userInput - quarters*25;
     
         dimes = userInput/10;
         userInput = userInput - dimes*10;
     
         nickels = userInput/5;
         userInput = userInput - nickels*5;   //Had to change the division, forgot to do that when copy and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    
      int userInput = scnr.nextInt();
      
      int change;
     
      int numDollars = (userInput / 100); 
      change = userInput % 100;
      int numQuarters = (change / 25);
      change = change % 25;
      int numDimes = (change / 10);
      change = change % 10;
      int numNickels = (change / 5);
      change = change % 5;
      int numPennies = (change / 1);
      change = change % 1;
     
      if (userInput <= 0) {
         System.out.println("No change");
      }
      else {
         if (numDollars == 1) {
            System.out.println(numDollars + " Dollar");
         }
         else if (numDollars > 1){
            System.out.println(numDollars + " Dollars");
         }
         
         if (numQuarters == 1) {
            System.out.println(numQuarters + " Quarter");
         }
         else if (numQuarters > 1) {
            System.out.println(numQuarters + " Quarters");
         }
         
         if (numDimes == 1) {
            System.out.println(numDimes + " Dime");
         }
         else if (numDimes > 1) {
            System.out.println(numDimes + " Dimes");
         }
         
         if (numNickels == 1) {
            System.out.println(numNickels + " Nickel");
         }
         else if (numNickels > 1) {
            System.out.println(numNickels + " Nickels");
         }
         
         if (numPennies == 1) {
            System.out.println(numPennies + " Penny");
         }
         else if (numPennies > 1) {
            System.out.println(numPennies + " Pennies");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).