# Calculating coins for money amount works for some values, but not for others

Tags: java

I have a second program due tomorrow and I have been working non stop to try to understand why some numbers work and others don't.

The general idea is that a person enters an amount of 'change', the program will run and separate that change into 'quarters', 'dimes', 'nickels', and 'pennies'. and this will keep happening until the person enters a zero instead of an integer. (Ignore the fact of the user inserting negative, or decimals. I just need this in int.)
My problem is that it's not processing these numbers: (1,2,3,4, 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,... etc.) Why?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //I have established and imported the Scanner in this line!
    
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        // bellow is where the variables are declared!
        int change = 0;
        int quarters = 0;
        int dimes = 0;
        int nickels = 0;
        int pennies = 0;
            
        // change inquiry in the following line 
        System.out.println("Please Enter an amount of change greater than zero or enter Zero to exit: ");
            
        //declaring the scanner variable and  preparing it for use 
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        change = myObj.nextInt(); //change input is inserted by user
            
        //if the change is not equal to zero then it will 
        //seperate the nuber into its respective coin count.
        while (change != 0){
            while (change >= 25){
                change = change - 25;
                quarters = quarters + 1;
            }
            while (change >= 10){
                change = change - 10;
                dimes = dimes + 1;
            }
            while (change >= 5){
                change = change - 5;
                nickels = nickels + 1;
                                   
                pennies = change;
                                    
                //finally ready to show the work the 
                //computer performed  with these print statements
                System.out.println("There are (is): " + quarters +" quarter(s),");
                System.out.println(dimes + " dime(s), ");
                System.out.println(nickels + " nickel(s), and ");
                System.out.println(pennies + pennies + " pennies left");
                                    
    
            }
            //this question will continue to be 
            //asked untill
            //Zero is entered which will then end 
            //the program.
            System.out.println("Please Enter a new amount of change greater than zero or enter Zero to exit: ");
            change = myObj.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question title should describe your problem well enough so that readers get the gist of what it's about. See: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: Your output is inside the nickels loop. In other words: move the `}` that is currently after the `System.out.println` statements printing the result to before `pennies = change`.

Comment: When your code is indented properly it is easier to follow the logic it is executing.

Comment: Some logic errors. Output being behind that >= 5 check is a major contributor.

Comment: Poor indentation is a classic mistake. See also [a similar question about splitting change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227906/exact-change-with-java?rq=1), which solves the problem with no loops. Welcome to StackOverflow! While people here generally really do want to help, you'll get more help if you follow the rules and show some effort. Read through the FAQ in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple logic errors in your code; first, your code to print the results is placed in the same while loop that counts nickels. If there is no need for a nickel to be counted, that code is never reached. Pennies are the same way. Therefore, any value of change that can be reached without using any nickels will error.

You also do not reset the values of each coin when asking for a new change value, so coins will add up over time. You can solve this by declaring the variables inside the loop, not outside.

When displaying pennies, you mistakenly add together two references to `pennies`, resulting in twice the amount that it should be.

Finally, for clarity, I recommend using -1 as your condition to exit the program, not 0, because `change = 0` is true at some point every time the loop runs and although the loop will not break, it is confusing.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int change = 0;
            
        // change inquiry in the following line 
        System.out.println("Please enter an amount of change or enter -1 to exit: ");
            
        //declaring the scanner variable and  preparing it for use 
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        change = myObj.nextInt(); //change input is inserted by user
            
        // if the input is not equal to -1, count change
        while (change != -1){

            // Redeclare each coin's count value inside this loop so that you start from 0 each time.
            int quarters = 0;
            int dimes = 0;
            int nickels = 0;
            int pennies = 0;

            // Count quarters
            while (change >= 25){
                change = change - 25;
                quarters = quarters + 1;
            }
            // Count dimes
            while (change >= 10){
                change = change - 10;
                dimes = dimes + 1;
            }
            // Count nickels
            while (change >= 5){
                change = change - 5;
                nickels = nickels + 1;
            }
            // Count pennies          
            pennies = change;

            // Done counting! Display results:   
            System.out.println("There are (is): " + quarters +" quarter(s),");
            System.out.println(dimes + " dime(s), ");
            System.out.println(nickels + " nickel(s), and ");
            System.out.println(pennies + pennies + " pennies left");
                                
            // Ask for a new change value.
            System.out.println("Please enter a new amount of change or enter -1 to exit: ");
            change = myObj.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rewriting the lines in question or pasting the code and annotating it with comments might help clarify the portion of the code for OP

Comment: Wow the indenting is so much better! This really helped me Thank you !! I tried fixing  this code so much that i ended up not seeing the out put inside the nickels bracket! The program now works exactly as designed! A million times thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the nickels loop should only calculate for nickels, not output the result.

Second, the values of each coin are not reset, so they will accumulate over time.

Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
            while (change >= 5){
            change = change - 5;
            nickels = nickels + 1;
        }
```

And then reset the values, and then you should be good.

Comment: Why do pennies need their own loop? Aren't they just the remainder?

Comment: Seems like you're right. Edited my reply.

Comment: Yes you highlighted the main reason why i was so upset with myself for not seeing such a simple fix haha! I've completed the changes i also needed to reset my variables at the end so that it would not continue adding up each time the loop repeated itself. The code now works exactly as designed! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I Appreciate all that you guys have done to help me! The code has been fixed! And a ton of anxiety and frustration has been removed from my shoulders! I appreciate you all. Im glad I found this website today! Here is the updated code and it performs exactly as designed in my assignment. I normally wouldnt include so many coments but i am getting graded on them as well so Here is the updated code!
again Thank you all who hleped me!

```
import java.util.Scanner; //I have established and imported the Scanner in this line!

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // bellow is where the variables are declared!
        int change = 0;
        int quarters = 0;
        int dimes = 0;
        int nickels = 0;
        int pennies = 0;
        
        // change inquiry in the following line 
        System.out.println("Please Enter an amount of change greater than zero or enter Zero to exit: ");
        
        //declaring the scanner variable and  preparing it for use 
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        change = myObj.nextInt(); //change input is inserted by user
        
        //if the change is not equal to zero then it will 
        //seperate the nuber into its respective coin count.
        while (change != 0){
            while (change >= 25){
                change = change - 25;
                quarters = quarters + 1;
            }
            while (change >= 10){
                change = change - 10;
                dimes = dimes + 1;
            }        
            while (change >= 5){
                change = change - 5;
                nickels = nickels + 1;                
            }                   
                pennies = change;
             //finally ready to show the work the 
              //computer performed  with these print statements
            System.out.println("There are (is): " + quarters +" quarter(s),");
            System.out.println(dimes + " dime(s), ");
            System.out.println(nickels + " nickel(s), and ");
            System.out.println( pennies + " pennies left");                                     
                               
            change = 0;
            quarters = 0;
            dimes = 0;
            nickels = 0;
            pennies = 0;                

                            
        //this question will continue to be 
        //asked untill
        //Zero is entered which will then end 
        //the program.
       System.out.println("Please Enter a new amount of change greater than zero or enter Zero to exit: ");
         change = myObj.nextInt();
        }
        
        
    
    }
}
```